# Access denied reading SAM subkeys on windows 7

Tags: windows, registry, access-denied

I wanna read SAM subkeys on Windows 7 using this code

```
int retVal = RegLoadKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SAM_AUX", @"E:\Auxiliar Registry\SAM");
RegistryKey accountKeys = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SAM_AUX\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\Names", false);
```

But I always receive Acces Denied, and I can't view SAM subkeys using regedit. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on the SAM registry keys don't allow access to ordinary users or to the Administrators group.  You could launch your process as local system (e.g., by making it a system service or by using psexec or the task scheduler) or you could enable the backup and restore privileges to bypass the security.

Comment: When you talk about enable the backup and resotre privileges, you mean this code:
    `OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, out _myToken)
    LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_RESTORE_NAME, out _restoreLuid)
    LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_BACKUP_NAME, out _backupLuid)`
How can I make a system service or use psexec if I am using VS 2013 with C#?

Comment: Well, there should be a call to `AdjustTokenPrivileges` somewhere, but yes.  Make sure you check `GetLastError()` after `AdjustTokenPrivileges` even if the return value is nonzero to see if you got `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`.  This will happen if you try to enable backup/restore privilege but don't actually hold it, e.g., if the application isn't being run elevated.  There are a set of C# classes for writing a service, though I'm not familiar with them myself.  The simplest way to use `psexec` would be to get the end user to use it to run your program, but you could also run it as a subprocess.

Comment: Ok. I did it, and I don´t have ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED, as well, I have no errors in that case. I will read C# classes for writing a service, maybe it could help me with my problem. Thanks anyway.